# Trying to create an NUnit test for WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit

I have referenced my WPF project to an NUnit Test Project I made. I am trying to call a function of it but I get the following **compilation** error:

```
Reference to type 'DependencyObject' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but it could not be found
```

I have added PresentationFramework, PresentationCore and WindowsBase as references in the "Assemblies" section of the NUnit test but no go... Not sure what I'm doing wrong... the code is very basic...

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using CM;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
    public class Tests
    {
        InstUserControl userControlMV = new InstUserControl ();

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            List<string> pOptions = new List<string>() { "2x4", "4x6" };
            userControlMV.SetPOptions(pOptions);
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I know that the NUnit has a version of .NET Core... and my WPF is 4.7.2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `NUnit Test Project (.NET Core)` to test a WPF application that targets the .NET Framework. Here is what you should do:

- Create a new `Unit Test Project (.NET Framwork)`
- Install the `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` NuGet packages into it
- Add a reference to the WPF project to be tested
- Add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll
- Add a reference to PresentationCore.cll
- Add a reference to WindowsBase.dll
- Run your tests.

Comment: Thanks mm8! What about adding a STAttribute or anything like that?

Comment: The `ApartmentAttribute` that you have decorated your `Tests` class with still applies.

Comment: Thanks mm8... always helping me out!!